# How to use preg_match in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, preg-match

I am not getting particular text in the defined variable

In normal PHP is working fine.. but when I uploaded this code in wordpress.. its not working.. throwing an error

```
$ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//SomeExampleStuff//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20190726T114808Z
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20190726T180000
DTSTAMP:20190726T114813Z
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20190726T170000
LAST-MODIFIED:20190726T114808Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Bajaj 
UID:A8H1C9CE-B911-466B-T04C-CP69098907K1
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';

if (! preg_match( '#^UID:(.*?)\r?\n?$#m', $ical, $matches ) ):
     echo "not fould";
      else: 
      $uid = $matches[1];
      echo $uid;
   endif;
```

I need only "UID:A8H1C9CE-B911-466B-T04C-CP69098907K1" from the `$ical` variable

Comment: Use `if (! preg_match( '#^UID:(.*)#m', $ical, $matches ) ) {
     echo "not found";
} else {
   $uid = $matches[1];
   echo $uid;
}`

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.. I added your code.. but its not working..it's showing not found..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the detailed report

The `preg`_ function such as `preg_match` is set in `php.ini`

`Pcre.backtrack_limit
 Pcre.recursion_limit`

If it exceeds the upper limit of the memory size, it seems to be an error.

Therefore, when large size is expected, it is necessary to process in other way avoiding preg_match, so replace it with the method using `strpos`, `substr` as advised.